# What can cause the same query on identical collections which are indexed the same way to return different results?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

Me and my teammates are using mongodb 1.8.2. Two out of three environments are working ok when running the following geospatial indexed query:

```
db.runCommand( {geoNear: "places", near: [-46.65069190000003, -23.5633661],
                maxDistance: 0.0006278449223041908, spherical: true,
                distanceMultiplier:  6371.0 });
```

against the following collection of 4032 documents:

```
{
  "ns" : "places",
  "count" : 4032,
  "size" : 1645724,
  "avgObjSize" : 408.1656746031746,
  "storageSize" : 2785280,
  "numExtents" : 4,
  "nindexes" : 2,
  "lastExtentSize" : 2097152, 
  "paddingFactor" : 1,
  "flags" : 1,
  "totalIndexSize" : 344064,
  "indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 180224,
    "location_2d" : 163840
  },
  "ok" : 1
}
```

running it in two distinct mongodb instances (one OSX Lion, other Ubuntu 11.04 server) the resultset contains 100 records with the following execution stats:

```
"stats" : {
   "time" : 0,
   "btreelocs" : 522,
   "nscanned" : 522,
   "objectsLoaded" : 146,
   "avgDistance" : 0.4824636947838318,
   "maxDistance" : 0.00012637762666867466
},
```

(Ok so far:The query is using the index, as you can see by the amount of btree node walks)

BUT in one of the environments(another OS X Lion) the results are drastically different(3 instead 100 from other machines) with exactly the same dataset and indexes:

```
"stats" : {
  "time" : 0,
  "btreelocs" : 45,
  "nscanned" : 50,
  "objectsLoaded" : 6,
  "avgDistance" : 0.865580980499049,
  "maxDistance" : 0.0001845858750423995
},
```

It's noticeable that the query is running differently in this mongod instance. What i'd like to know is which factors can make this happen

What i tried so far:

- Mongodb server and client versions are the same (including git hash)
- The supposedly weird database has been wiped out, restored from a BSON dump and indexes recreated

Version info:

```
db version v1.8.2, pdfile version 4.5
Tue Aug 23 23:33:22 git version: 433bbaa14aaba6860da15bd4de8edf600f56501b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm actually wondering about the data integrity here. The "bad" data set basically did about one tenth of the work of the good data set. Almost like it just decided to stop part-way through and not tell you what was going on.

MongoDB has a `validate` command that can double-check the integrity of a collection. Would you be able to run that and see if anything comes up?

Link to command [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Validate+Command).

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately i did not have to opportunity to run this command on the collection since i managed to drop the database properly via db.dropDatabase(). My best guess is that it would point the data problem that was causing the query to behave that way. The reason that my previous wipe attempts weren't working was because i was deleting the files believing that mongod was down (but it was being automagically started by Cellar as soon as i killed it).

Answer (score 0):

If the number returned is exactly 100 then I am suspicious that your results sets are different because there are more than 100 points with the specified distance. Therefore the DB  is free to pick just the first 100 points that meet the criteria.

Is there a way to increase the result size to something like 2000 or reduce the distance to something smaller.

Comment: Makes total sense, but in this case the resultset difference was way too big (3 vs the 100 from the other two environments). I haven't made that clear in the question. Just edited it :)